# Visual Studio could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have been working on a MVC5 project using Visual Studio Community Edition on Windows 10. One fine morning, when I started Visual Studio to resume work and run the webapp I got the following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its
>   dependencies.

What really happened all of a sudden, I have absolutely no clue. . It's my personal machine.
Can anyone please help me out? What happened to my dear Visual Studio? Is it sick or something?

I have tried all the things that are mentioned in a similar question asked on SO. In that question the OP compiled his own version of ASP.NET from its sources. I have not performed any such thing. Those Jks. who have been finding similarity in that question should read the 2 questions fully before declaring that they are exact duplicates.

Comment: Protip: calling people "jerks" is probably not going to help you in getting an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps might help:

1.Right click your solution and select open folder in file explorer.

2.Close your visual studio.

3.Delete .vs folder.

4.Open Visual Studio as administrator.

5.Clean and Build Solution.